# Infinite sum with an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Trying to find the variance of the logistic distribution I have come to this expression. I tried to solve the integral separately, but this procedure is not working. Can someone guide me on how to solve the problem?
\begin{equation}
 E(x^{2})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^{2}}dx
= 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n(-1)^{n-1}\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int^{p}_{0}x^{2}e^{-nx}dx
\end{equation}

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution#Higher_order_moments

Comment: Do you need any thoughts on how to get to the second equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Integration by parts yields
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-nx} dx &= -x^2\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\bigg|_0^\infty +\frac{2}{n} \int_0^\infty x e^{-nx}dx\\&=\frac{2}{n}\left[-x \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\bigg |_0^\infty + \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}dx\right]\\&= \frac{2}{n^3}\end{align}$$

and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{2}{n^2} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}} $$

Comment: You can also let $x=y/n$ to get this.

Comment: Why in the second step the limits are 2/n^3?.I try and try and get as a result 0+0, by l'hopital in the first term and the second directly

Comment: Clearly $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{nx}} = 0$$ and is not difficult to see that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-nx} = 0$$

Comment: Yes. But why $\frac{2}{n}\left[0+0\right]=\frac{2}{n^{3}}$?

Comment: The integral, for sure, is $\frac{1}{n}$. I don't understand your question.

Comment: hahaha sorry, I was thinking only in the infinity. Thanks you!

Comment: You're most welcome!